# Building a Custom Browser in JavaFx 8

Tags: javafx, browser, javafx-8, flash

I am interested in building a custom browser in javafx 8 using the WebView component as a personal project.  One of the features I hope to include is the ability to play flash video / sound.  I'm not sure where to start so I'm hoping someone here could give me a few pointers as to how I'd go about accomplishing this.

Also, if you're aware of any resources out there that might come in handy when it comes to adding additional functionality I'd appreciate it.  I'm hoping to make this fairly full featured.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by _"...play flash video / sound"_? Do you mean `.flv` video files? Or you mean Flash applications (`.swf` files) that happen to load files of mp3/aac audio and mp4/flv videos?

Comment: Ideally, full flash functionality - say, play a flash game.  Minimally, I'd like to be able to handle flash video and sound.

Comment: so yes .flv files

Answer (score 1):

I'd stop this project because WebView does not support flash videos.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm

Comment: Thanks.  I was pretty sure this was the case but was hoping someone out there might have a workaround,  But that is highly doubtful and yes, this does slam the brakes on it :)

This isn't necessarily directed to you but, wow... I fail to see how this question merits a downvote.

Comment: I was not the downvoter. I think downvotes without an identifiable, related comment should be made impossible on SO. I just wanted to save you some wasted work with my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I found a component that meets my requirements.  JxBrowser.

https://dzone.com/articles/htmlcssjavascript-gui-java-0

https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser

Comment: Or you could go with html5,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML5_and_Flash  It's a more modern solution unless you need to support legacy flash.